# Dynamic Memory Allocation for Dictionary

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, allocation

Hi there I need to Build something like a dictionary and each word according to my code can have 100 meanings, but maybe it has only 5 meanings then I will be allocating 95 extra space for nothing or maybe it has more than 100 meanings then the program will crash, I know the vector class is very easy and could be good use of, but the task is almost building my own vector class, to learn how it works. Thus **meanings and some other stuff remain the same and here is my code, Also I know I am causing memory leakage, how can I delete properly? :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Expression {

    char *word_with_several_meanings; // like "bank", "class"
    char **meanings; // a pointer to a pointer stores all meanings
    int meanings_ctr; // meanings counter

    //-----------FUNCTIONS------------------------------------------------
public:
    void word( char* = NULL );
    void add_meaning(char* = NULL);
    char* get_word();
    int get_total_number_of_meanings();
    char* get_meaning(int meanx = 0);
    Expression(int mctr = 0); // CTOR
    ~Expression(); // DTOR
};

  Expression::Expression(int mctr ) {
  meanings_ctr = mctr;          // Setting the counter to 0
  meanings = new char * [100]; // Allocate Space for 100 meanings
}

Expression::~Expression() {
 delete [] meanings; // Deleting the memory we allocated
 delete [] word_with_several_meanings; // Deleting the memory we allocated
}

void Expression::word( char *p2c )
{

    word_with_several_meanings = new char[strlen(p2c)+1];
// copy the string, DEEP copy
    strcpy(word_with_several_meanings, p2c);
}

void Expression::add_meaning(char *p2c)
{

    //meanings = new char * [meanings_ctr+1];
    meanings[meanings_ctr] = new char[strlen(p2c)+1];
    strcpy(meanings[meanings_ctr++],p2c);


}

char * Expression::get_meaning( int meanx )
{

    return *(meanings+meanx);

}

char * Expression::get_word()
{

    return word_with_several_meanings;

}

int Expression::get_total_number_of_meanings()
{

    return meanings_ctr;

}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    Expression expr;
    expr.word("bank ");
    expr.add_meaning("a place to get money from");
    expr.add_meaning("b place to sit");
    expr.add_meaning("4 letter word");
    expr.add_meaning("Test meaning");
    cout << expr.get_word() << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<expr.get_total_number_of_meanings(); i++)
            cout << " " << expr.get_meaning(i)  << endl;
    Expression expr2;
    expr2.word("class");
    expr2.add_meaning("a school class");
    expr2.add_meaning("a classification for a hotel");
    expr2.add_meaning("Starts with C");
    cout << expr2.get_word() << endl;
    for( i = 0; i<expr2.get_total_number_of_meanings(); i++)
            cout << " " << expr2.get_meaning(i) << endl;

        Expression expr3;
    expr3.word("A long test ... ");
    char str[] = "Meaning_      ";
    for (int kx=0;kx<26;kx++)
    {
            str[8] = (char) ('A'+kx);
            expr3.add_meaning(str);
    }

cout << expr3.get_word() << endl;
for(i = 0; i < expr3.get_total_number_of_meanings(); i++)
    cout << " " << expr3.get_meaning(i) << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is typo within your destructor.

Comment: The correct solution is to use `std::multimap<std::string, std::string>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you are allocating a multi dimensional array with `new` then you are allocating it with a loop, e.g.

```c
char **x = new char*[size]
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = new int[size];
}
```

So you also have to delete it in this fashion:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    delete[] x[i];
}
delete[] x;
```

Thus when you're having arbitrary sizes of your array you'll have to store them somewhere for using them within the destructor.

Comment: Hi Sebastian thanks for the reply, the delete part I solved with a while loop, similar approach to yours.I tried to implement something similar to your first part but it didnt work, the problem here is I dont know how long will the "size" be in my case?

Comment: I don't know either. It depends, so for instance if you'll have to implement something like vector you'll have to reallocate memory. Maybe then it's good to allocate a bit more and you'll have to save the current allocated size. For reallocation you'll have to `new` first, copy and delete the old pointer afterwards.

Comment: I tried to make it with a **temp_meanings pointer to pointer but it didnt work ... I have like 3-4 for loops, for copying and deleting and then reallocating ... probably the loops are too complicated and there is a mistake somewhere .. I tried to use the debugger of MS Visual Studio 2010 but it sucks .. any more tips?

Comment: Maybe write a new question regarding this specific topic, include some (only the relevant parts) code and ask again.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete [] meanings; // Deleting the memory we allocated
```

won't get rid of your memory allocated, only the pointers themselves.

To free up the actual memory, you will need to iterate through your `meanings` array, and `delete []` each element in it.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < meanings_ctr; ++i)
{
    delete [] meanings[meanings_ctr];
    meanings[meanings_ctr] = NULL;
}
delete [] meanings;
```

--

For the problem of what to do if you get more than 100 meanings (or in general when your collection is full), the standard technique is to allocate a new array that is double the size (which you can do since it is dynamic), copy your existing collection into that one, and then dispose of your existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple linked list (this is simplified, not complete and untested; also there should be proper getters/setters and stuff):

```
class Meaning {
    char text[20];
    Meaning *next;

    Meaning(const char *text) : next(0) {
        strcpy(this->text, text);
    }
}

class Word {
    char text[20];
    Meaning *first;
    Meaning *last;

    Word(const char *text) : first(0), last(0) {
        strcpy(this->text, text);
    }

    ~Word() {
        Meaning *m = first, *n;
        while(m) {
            n = m->next;
            delete m;
            m = n;
        }
    }

    void AddMeaning(const char *text) {
        if (last) {
            last = last->next = new Meaning(text);
        }
        else {
            first = last = new Meaning(text);
        }
    }

    void print() {
        printf("%s:\n\t", text);
        Meaning *m = first;
        while (m) {
            printf("%s, ", m->text);
            m = m->next;
        }
    }
}
```